# Python and Anaconda breakdown

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

My anaconda program does not work anymore, it happened all of a sudden. I suspect it was due to the failure of upgrading pip using PowerShell. I already uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda, and I deleted most of my current python directory. but the problem remains unsolved. The error message is like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFxXd.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors (and code if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].